# Efficient iteration over a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 2D(nxm) array and the entries of the 1st row and 1st column are given.
Initially the elements in the matrix are "X" except for the first row and column.
Finally the elements in the array are either "L" or "W".
The (0,0) element doesn't matter. I have taken it to be "-" in the below given example.

```
For Example: l=[- W L W]
               [L X X X]
               [W X X X] .
```

Here n=3 and m=4, now i start iterating from l[1][1].

I have to check only the cells that are on top of it and to the left if it, i.e 
(0,1) and (1,0) in the case of (1,1).

If either one of them (either the left cell or the top cell) contains "L" in it then l[1][1] will be filled with "W" else "L". In the case of l[1][1] , it will be filled with "W" as the cell left to it i.e (1,0) contains "L" in it.

Now the whole process has to be repeated and i have to fill up the whole matrix with either "L" or "W" according to the given above condition.

i have tried using brute force(iterating over every element and then checking the left and top cell). I am looking for a more efficient solution.

The final matrix of the above example will look like this after filling up all the elements according to the given condition:

```
l=[- W L W]
  [L W W L]
  [W L W W]
```

Also, i'm trying to implement this in python.

Comment: Please include a _legal_ Python matrix in your example.

Comment: It is easier to answer when there is a question.

Comment: Am i not clear with the question? Can you please tell which part is not clear?